# Opening any user control within a certain project crashes Visual Studio 2010. How do I fix it?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010

Working with forms in my main C# project has gotten progressively more unstable, but now it has gotten to the point where I cannot even create a brand new User Control, because Visual Studio 2010 crashes immediately.

This has been an issue on several different machines (WinXP, and Win7), so I assume it has something to do with the project settings.

I have tried debugging opening controls with a separate VS instance, but it doesn't seem to even reach the constructor of the control.

Are the any suggestions for tracking this down?

Comment: How big is the project? How many files? What kind of C# project (website, winforms, MVC...)? Are there any third party controls you are using? Does it compile cleanly, with all warnings enabled, treating warnings as errors? If the project is small enough and modular enough, is it feasible to create a new project and add things one item at a time?

Comment: Bob, it's a winforms project with ~850 c# files. There are about 12 third party dll's, 3 of which are controls.

Comment: Bob, thanks for your questions. I tried removing the 3 third party custom controls from the project, and then opening my controls with the winforms editor, and it worked! I readded the controls and it's still working.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to remove references to third party controls and add them back in. Thanks Bob Kaufmann.